# How to remove outdoor paint from furniture

Tags: furniture, paint-removal

Workmen splattered red paint all over my grey outdoor furniture. The table is glass and metal. The chairs are metal with woven seats. How can I clean the paint off the woven part of the chairs, the metal arms, and the glass tabletop? I know nothing about home improvement.

Comment: Why not ask the workmen to clean up their mess?

Comment: Absolutely should be the responsibility of the painting contractor! If it's a reputable company, they'll want to fix it. If it's... less than reputable, well I hope you haven't paid the final amount yet - withhold the final payment until the job is done satisfactorily. Also, take pics _now_ to show damage (or lack thereof) _before_ they start cleaning, so you've got proof that things weren't damaged before they started cleaning up.

Comment: How long ago? ...

Comment: This happened yesterday. I didnt hire them, the landlord hired them to paint our back stairs. And then the paint disaster happened. I can try to ask them to clean it, but what do I do if they refuse?

Comment: Try a steam cleaner ASAP; should melt off fresh paint.

Comment: If a laytex paint get some latex paint remover right away , more than a few days old it won’t work well. My wife puts my clothes in a bucket with a cup of remover and then washes works well (I hate painting and am one of those messy guys).

Answer (score 0):

The glass is easy, you can just use a product called "Goof Off". The bigger problem will be the paint on other paint, because the Goof Off will not discriminate between the two. The hope would be that because the red paint is so new, it will come off BEFORE the older paint does, but that's not likely. Whether it works on the woven parts will depend on what the material is; if it's a plastic, the Goof Off may attack it.